QLIstView with interactive custom widgets
I'm developing a list using QLIstView in C++/Qt, based on the view/model technology.
I wish each item in the list to be a custom widget (derived from QWidget), thereby better displaying multidimensional data.
Also, each item (custom widget) must be able to be easily interacted with, such as a shadow effect when the mouse is hovered.
How can I achieve this?
The delegate can display custom widgets by drawing them into pictures.
But this will not allow interaction.

Images should only be used when they are actually needed as such, certainly not to display a widget. Delegates have the createEditor() which return an actual widget (possibly based on the data type or the model index, it's normally called by a view when the user starts editing an item, or can be programmatically done through openPersistentEditor(). Note that by interaction I mean allowing the user to edit the model data. If you only need graphics effects, you just have to override paint() (and, possibly, editorEvent()).

You are wrong to say item delegates do not allow interaction. IMO, you have 2 options. The first is to use a delegate and implement either createEditor() or editorEvent() (but likely not both) for user interaction. Alternatively, have a look at QAbstractItemView::setIndexWidget.

The former approach can get quite complicated but works for models of any size and be faster than the latter: views are optimized to only paint indexes that are on screen with 1 delegate only whereas setIndexWidget requires you to create as many widgets as your model has indexes (which you cannot do in a separate thread since they are widgets) and that very much includes indexes not visible (yet). Beginner Qt developers will typically implement setIndexWidget whereas experienced Qt developers may go through the trouble of implementing a custom delegate.
